# converting 2d points on an picture to a 3d plane

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry

I want to ask the same question as from [this tread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog), about planar homograph but using absolute values so I can visualize it.

My goal is to retrieve 3D transformations of a plane (position/rotation related to the camera) from within a picture. I am not sure if homograph is what I need. Please correct me if not.

*[Here is the link for the picture I am analysing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7pazp3wqnrt9la/squareinfo.jpg):*

Lets say my points on the image plane are:

```
p[0] = x:407 y:253
p[1] = x:386 y:253
p[2] = x:406 y:232
p[3] = x:385 y:232
```

these points are in a 500px width x 333px height image plane with 0,0 at top left corner. These points represents the corners of 30mm side square contained in a picture. Assuming this picture was taken by a fixed camera at origin heading Z axis.

So, I know the physical distance between p0,p1 ; p0,p2 ; p1,p3; p2,p3 are 30mm and they are co-planar.

But is it possible to get the X,Y,Z of each point only using this information above so I can recreate the 3D plane?

EDIT*
[Here a link to what it seems to be a very well explained theory of what I am looking for (from page 34)](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/courses/ARVU/ARVU1b.pdf)
I can't follow it very well however...

*ps: Moderator, excuse me. I am not sure if I should post a new tread or extend the question on the previous tread. Please feel free to delete this tread if necessary.*