# Differences between homography and transformation matrix

Tags: transformation, computer-vision

I'm wondering whats the differences between a homography and a transformation matrix?

For me it's kinda look like the same? Or is homography just the more precise word in the area of computer vision and transformation of image plane?

Comment: What would you say is the difference between a linear transformation and a matrix?

Comment: @amd thats literally what I'm asking ?!

Comment: A transformation is a *function*. A matrix is an array of numbers that can represent a transformation. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @amd well I wasn't asking for the difference between an transformation and a matrix. I was asking for the difference between a homopgrahy and a transformation matrix. But in the mean time I found the difference on my own

Comment: A homography is a particular type of transformation. The difference between that and a matrix is exactly the same: the latter is one possible *representation* of the former.

Answer (score 10):

The term *homography* is often used in the sense of *homography matrix* in computer vision. In maths, I guess, the term *homography* describes the substatial concept, not the matrix. So the question is: What is the difference between homography matrix and transformation matrix?

The mathematical name for homography concept is "*projective transformation*" ([source](https://cs.gmu.edu/~zduric/cs682/Slides/homography.pdf)) and in computer vision it refers to transforming images such as if they were taken under different perspective. This is a much narrower question than any arbitrary transformation and hence **homography can be computed by using mathematical tricks** ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog) for details), **avoiding geometrical computations**. The effect of applying the matrix should be the same, but the way to get this matrix is easier.

An example [from opencv](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/): we have two images of the same place, taken from different angle. We will compute homography H. If we now select one pixel with coordinates (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) from the first image and another pixel (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) that represents the same point on another image, we can transform the latter pixel to have the same viewing perspective as the first one by applying H:

[image: OpenCV example of applying homography]

As we see, it is identical to applying transformation matrix, hence homography is just a special case of transformation. Most examples that I have seen, consider homography only for 2D (i.e., for images). Still, homography can be extended to larger dimension ([source](https://ags.cs.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/inf_ags/3dcv-ws11-12/3DCV_WS11-12_lec04.pdf)). Thanks to homography, 3D to 2D planar projection (i.e., mapping [coordinates in 3D space to points on 2D plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_projection)) reduces to 2D to 2D, i.e., to a less complex problem ([source](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture16.pdf)).

While transformation is very general concept and includes all kinds of conversions, including conversion between coordinate frames, homography is a subset of it, mostly only applied when rotation is needed ([source](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~c_shu/Courses/comp4900d/notes/homography.pdf)). In computer vision it is a technical term that describes above-mentioned case of transformation. You can achieve the same result by using proper geometrical transformation, but it will be more complex.

Answer (score 3):

[MF.OX's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2745139/281166) still leaves some points of wonder:

Is a homography constrained in some way, or can any matrix ($3\times3$) be a homography matrix in homogeneous 2d space?

I found out that yes, a homography matrix's elements are unconstrained - and it is synonymous to a projectivity. To answer the question of what a homography actually is, it is useful to compare the concept of a homography also to Affinity, Similarity, Euclidean Transforms, etc. Those are all constrained more strongly, so the word homography is useful to explicitly state that the matrix *may* not adhere to those stronger constraints.

To this purpose, I find this comparison useful:
[image: Hierarchy of 2d Transformations]
Source: https://www.cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/3dvision/2020/slides/class02eth20.pdf

So a "transformation matrix" is a general term and a "homography" is technically the same, but I believe it is used mainly to point out that there are no further constraints. That is, I would not say that an Affine Transformation is a Homography when I know that it is always affine. But I would call an Affine Transformation a Transformation - like wikipedia does [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), for example.