# Check if the Quadrilateral is a perspective projection of a rectangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

Given the convex quadrilateral Q. The problem is to determine if $\exists$ a rectangle and a camera perspective projection matrix M (3x4), so that Q = M*R.

My question is similar: [Mapping Irregular Quadrilateral to a Rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13404/266666) but not exactly duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**Every** strictly convex quadrilateral (with angles strictly less than $180^\circ$) is the perspective projection of a rectangle.

In the projective plane, identify the two points where opposite sides of the quadrilateral intersect. It is always possible with a projective transformation to move two different points to points that are $90^\circ$ apart on the line at infinity. This transformation takes the entire original quadrilateral to a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you clarify what does "points that are 90∘90∘ apart on the line at infinity" mean? I could not understand this with my low English.

Comment: Do you need a constructive way to find the rectangle and the point of view V ? I mean by that, that given 4 points $P_k(x_k,y_k)$ in the xOy plane, you want to know the coordinates of V as functions of the $x_k$ and $y_k$ and points $Q_k(X_k,Y_k)$ that can be candidates for being the vertices of the rectangle ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, actually no. I'm just finding a way to filter out quadrilaterals detected on image, which are not rectangles.