# Line uniting 2 segments at a specific ratio and crossing a point between the two

Tags: geometry

I have two segments one above the other and they do not cross, and a point$\ p $ between the two. 
I must draw a line that connects the 2 segments and the point, each of the line's ends is at a ratio of the distance between the two points of each segment. 
That ratio must be the same for both top and bot segment and starts from the left to right.

[see image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYrlB.png)

$\ tl $ = top left corner 
$\ tr $ = top right corner 
$\ bl $ = bottom left corner 
$\ br $ = bottom right corner

Here is how I tried to solve the problem:

x = amount of distance between either points of a segment, takes values between 0 and 1  
top = the line's top point that connects with the top segment 
bot = the line's bot point that connects with the bot segment

top = $\ (1 - x) tl + x tr $ 
bot = $\ (1 - x) bl + x br $

top_dist = distance between$\ p$ and$\ top$ 
bot_dist = distance between$\ p$ and$\ bot$ 
sum_dist = distance$\ bot$ and$\ bot$

top_dist = $\sqrt{(p_u - top_u)^2 + (p_v - top_v)^2} $ 
bot_dist = $\sqrt{(p_u - bot_u)^2 + (p_v - bot_v)^2} $ 
sum_dist = $\sqrt{(bot_u - top_u)^2 + (bot_u - top_v)^2} $

Ensure $\ top$, $\ bot$ and $\ p$ are collinear 
top_dist + bot_dist - sum_dist = 0

$$\sqrt{[p_u - ((1 - x) tl_u + x tr_u)] ^2 + [p_v - ((1 - x) tl_v + x tr_v)] ^2} + 
\sqrt{[p_u - ((1 - x) bl_u + x br_u)] ^2 + [p_v - ((1 - x) bl_v + x br_v)] ^2} - 
\sqrt{[((1 - x) bl_u + x br_u) - ((1 - x) tl_u + x tr_u)] ^2 +
      [((1 - x) bl_v + x br_v) - ((1 - x) tl_v + x tr_v)] ^2} = 0 $$
Solving parametrically I get to:

$$\sqrt{a x^2 + b x + c} + 
\sqrt{d x^2 + e x + f} - 
\sqrt{g x^2 + h x + i} = 0 $$
And I am stuck, can't get x out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bilinear interpolation in a quadrilateral is the thing that I needed, see http://reedbeta.com/blog/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-2/.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\{t_l, t_r, b_l, b_r\}$ defines a quadrilateral, call it $Q$. From here, we can clarify the requirements a bit:

- Instead of constraining $t$ "above" $b$, we can instead constrain ourselves to cases where $Q$ is **simple** (no intersecting edges) and **convex**. This characterisation also excludes degenerate cases such as when $t$ and $b$ don't form a quadrilateral.
- Point $p$ must be an **interior point** of $Q$.

We get some nice properties when we map $Q$ to the unit square, $Q'$, such that $t_l = (0,1)$, $t_r = (1,1)$, $b_l = (0,0)$, and $b_r = (1,0)$.

- The x coordinate of the projected point $p' = (p'_x, p'_y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ is the ratio.
- The line segment from $(p'_x,0)$ to $(p'_x,1)$ is our solution after applying the **inverse map**.
- Such a line **exist** since $p'$ is also an interior point of the unit square. It is also **unique** since the (projected) line must be vertical in order to have the same ratio on $t'$ and $b'$, there is only one such vertical line passing through $p'$.

Perspective projection should do for the mapping above. The mathematics will be a little more involved and I am not too familiar with it so you may consider [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104595/516832) as a guide that specifically handles this particular step.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that the resulted quadrilateral is convex