# What algorithm can I use to find this ellipse inscribed in a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

There's a certain drawing exercise designed to improve a drawing student's understanding of perspective and ability to draw shapes freehand. (The actual exercise is described by Irshad Karim on Drawabox.com, on the pages "[Ghosted Planes](https://drawabox.com/lesson/1/ghostedplanes)" and "[Ellipses in Planes](https://drawabox.com/lesson/1/ellipsesinplanes)".)

The exercise consists of drawing a convex quadrilateral, then drawing a window-like structure inside the quadrilateral, and finally drawing the ellipse implied by this structure.

Ideally, the result will look similar to this diagram:

[image: A diagram of a drawing exercise]

The exact steps of the exercise are:

1. Draw any convex quadrilateral $ABCD$.
2. Draw the diagonals of the quadrilateral; call their intersection point $E$.
3. Draw a line segment passing through $E$, which is *concurrent* to the edges $AD$ and $BC$. (Line segments are *concurrent* if they are all parallel, or if, when they are extended to lines, the resulting lines all intersect at a single point.) One endpoint should lie on $AB$, and be labeled $F$; the other endpoint should lie on $CD$, and be labeled $G$.
4. Likewise, draw a line segment passing through $E$, which is concurrent to the edges $AB$ and $CD$. One endpoint lies on $AD$ and is labeled $H$, the other lies on $BC$ and is labeled $J$.
5. Finally, draw the unique ellipse which is tangent to $ABCD$ at $F$, $G$, $H$, and $J$.

**Given the coordinates of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, what algorithm can be used to find the resulting ellipse?**

I'm not 100% sure that there *is* always a unique ellipse tangent to $ABCD$ at $F$, $G$, $H$ and $J$, but it definitely seems like there is. There's always a unique ellipse which is tangent at $F$ and which passes through $G$, $H$, and $J$; and from experimentation, it looks like this ellipse is always tangent at $G$, $H$ and $J$ as well.

In the case where $ABCD$ is a square, everything is especially simple. The resulting ellipse is the circle inscribed in the square. I suspect that every case is simply the image of this case under some type of perspective transformation which preserves ellipses. But I don't know how to prove this, or how to make use of this fact.

Comment: Interesting question, although I think the point of the original freehand-drawing exercise is _not_ to use an algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a projective transformation that takes the quadrilateral to a square.  Draw a circle inscribed in the square, transform back and you get an ellipse inscribed in the quadrilateral.

The answers to this question describe how to find a projective transformation which takes the quadrilateral to a square: [Mapping Irregular Quadrilateral to a Rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/mapping-irregular-quadrilateral-to-a-rectangle)

Comment: This is the help that I needed, thank you! I went ahead and edited your answer by adding a link to another question with more information; please feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @TannerSwett I find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/265466) the best of the descriptions of how to construct the required homography.